# Parsing an Excel file from an online Endpoint Using python

Tags: python, flask

There is an excel spreadsheet that lives on an endpoint, where when pinged by a get request will return an excel speadsheet .xlsx. It works on postman, however predictably returns a binary that it cannot understand. How can i go about consuming this file as a pandas dataframe (or similar), parse a row, then return a JSON using python flask?

Answer (score 0):

For Python, you may download the spreadsheet file to a temporary directory using a library such as [`urllib.request`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html).

```
import urllib.request


urllib.request.urlretrieve(SPREADSHEET_URL, SAVE_AS_NAME.xlsx)
```

Once the file has been downloaded, simply load the spreadsheet file into your library of choice. For example, Pandas:

```
import pandas as pd


df = pd.read_excel(SAVE_AS_NAME)
...
# The first row all columns
df.loc[0,:]
```